# Electrum seed does not work when put into iancoleman's site

Tags: electrum

I used Electrum to make a new wallet and I copied out the twelve word seed. I then copied this into https://iancoleman.io/bip39. From previous experience a few years ago, I expected this to generate a number of addresses and keys. I ticked the BIP39 derivation path. It stated that it was calculating but it was still calculating 30 minutes later. I did something wrong ...??

Comment: Since you've pasted this seed into a website, I'm assuming it's just a throwaway seed not meant for actual funds. If that's correct, can you include the seed in your question so others can try to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Electrum does not generate bip39 seeds.

[https://electrum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/seedphrase.html#description:~:text=For%20these%20reasons%2C%20Electrum%20does%20not%20generate%20BIP39%20seeds](https://electrum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/seedphrase.html#description:%7E:text=For%20these%20reasons%2C%20Electrum%20does%20not%20generate%20BIP39%20seeds)

Comment: Accepted. Wallet technology has moved on since 2017.